# Urwid ProgessBar does not update properly

Tags: python, progress-bar, tui, urwid

I'm playing around with the urwid library and it's been pretty great so far.
But i can't get the Progressbar to work. I wrote a simple test program like this:

```
import os
import urwid

    # a function that takes some times to complete
def dosomething(steps, bar):
    bar.done = steps
    for i in range(steps + 1):
        bar.set_completion(i)
        os.system('sleep 0.2')

    # make a button to start
task_btn = urwid.Button(u'Task')
    # progressbar object
pbar = urwid.ProgressBar('pg normal', 'pg complete')

    # function called when the task button is clicked
def on_task_clicked(button):
    dosomething(10, pbar)

    # setup signal handler for the button
urwid.connect_signal(task_btn, 'click', on_task_clicked)

    """
     create the interface and the mainloop.
     filler objects are our friend to prevent unpacking errors :D
   """

loop = urwid.MainLoop(urwid.Pile([urwid.Filler(task_btn), urwid.Filler(pbar)]))
loop.run()
```

If i start it the progressbar is to 0% as it should be. Then i press the button, and a few seconds later the progressbar shows 100%. but i'm missing the steps between 0% and 100%. they just won't show up.

Also an additional call of the render function won't work.

I've also tried something like this:

```
def on_task_clicked(button):
    pbar.set_completion(pbar.current+1)
```

And this works just fine. It just seems that the progressbar is not happy with being called in a loop. That seems strange?! Someone got any ideas in order to resolve this?

Thanks in advance :)

PS: 
INFO:
urwid 1.2.0
tested on python 2.6.6, 2.7, 3.3 all the same

Answer (score 3):

It's probably because the main loop's `draw_screen` method isn't being called (it's normally called automatically when the loop enters the idle state).

Add `loop.draw_screen()` inside your for-loop.

Comment: Adding the `loop.draw_screen()` worked for me (Python 3.6 and urwid 1.3.1). But I think it would be necessairy to create a function that updates it on any change of the percentage. Don't know if it possible though.